# How to use multiple proxy in urllib2?

Tags: python, proxy, urllib2

Hello
I'm have a task - create script, what will walk in internet and change proxy from list.
I'm see in module urllib2: ProxyHandler and HTTPPasswordMgr, but manual is poor.
1. In documentation ProxyHandler get dict with many proxy-server, how to I'm can select from list and use for url_open?
2. HTTPPasswordMgr have method add_password, but for what it? How to it will select auth-data for proxy, for what it have: realm?
3. How to right use multiple proxy in urllib2? I'm think only create a list with all my proxy and create new 'opener' for each request.
Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`ProxyHandler` can use a different proxy for different protocols (HTTP, etc.) but I don't think it will help you.  You should be able to write your own class for your needs without much difficulty.